# Django - Slug field must be unique for a user but not for all user

Tags: django, django-models

I know we can require that the SlugField be unique with unique=True option, but is it possible to require it to be unique only for a particular user, so two different user could have the same SlugField but a user cannot have two identical slugField?

models. py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ezApp(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    in_use = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: This would be then done either in form validation or on save() override

Comment: Im struggling to see the point of this? It feels as if youre designing it wrong? Im thinking in urls you would be able to have http://mysite.com/profiles/limelights-rocker and http://mysite.com/profiles/limelights-rocker and it should point towards two diffrent userprofiles? Please, elaborate further as I want to know the usecase for this! :D

Comment: @limelights, yes this is exactly what i want to do. This site absolutely needs  a login to enter. Its normal to allow different users to have articles with the same slug. There is no confusion if you do the query with request.user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use unique_together as detailed here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'created_by')
```

You'll have to do some babysitting at the form level too, so the user gets usable error messages when they try to add duplicate names.

Comment: Damn, you beat me by seconds. +1 though

Comment: unique_together works when you create an article with django admin site, but its not working when I create an article directly with a form... any idea why?